# Есть ли возможность в Ynadex MapKit получать карты с indoor схемой помещения?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает. Не могу найти в Яндекс MapKit как получать карту с внутренней схемой помещения. На Web у них есть такая возможность, а в MapKit я не смог найти. Может есть какие то дополнительные настройки карты? Или там в принципе не возможно получить indoor схему торгового центра к примеру?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Сам же и нашел ответ, после долгого поиска в сети.  Свойство isIndoorEnabled = true решило проблему.